# How to get select option and put them in an array?, playwright + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, playwright

I am trying to use Playwright to locate and extract all options/text from the third select HTML element and push it to an array? I have tried different alternatives, page.locate(), page.$$eval() and page.evaluate(). My goal is to loop over the options in the third select element and get the data from each option.

```
    "playwright": "^1.40.1"
```

```
const { chromium } = require("playwright");

const url = `<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app" data-v-app="">
        <div class="f-container fixed-hf">
            <header>
                HEADER
            </header>
            <main class="flex flex-col main mx-0 sm:mx-32">
                <div class="w-full">
                    <div class="flex justify-end p-1 border border-slate-300 shadow-lg overflow-auto">
                        HEADER BUTTONS
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex flex-wrap h-full">
                    <div class="w-full md:w-3/12 border-x-2 border-gray-300 bg-slate-100">
                        <div class="flex flex-col p-2 m-1 border border-slate-300 shadow-lg">
                            <div class="w-full sm:w-12/12 px-1">
                                <h2>Other links</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex flex-col p-2 m-2">
                            <div>
                                <label for="first_select">First Select:</label>
                                <select class="select">
                                    <option value="[object Object]">One</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">Two</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">Three</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">Fourth</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">Five</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">Six</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">Seven</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="w-full">
                                <label for="second_select">Second Select:</label>
                                <select class="select">
                                    <option value="[object Object]">A</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">B</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">C</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">D</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">E</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">F</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">G</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">H</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">Y</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">J</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">K</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">L</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">M</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">N</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">O</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">P</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">Q</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">R</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="w-full">
                                <label for="third_select">Third Select:</label>
                                <select class="select">
                                    <option value="[object Object]">11</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">22</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">33</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">44</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">45</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">46</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">47</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">48</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">49</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">50</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">51</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">52</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">53</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">54</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">55</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">56</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">57</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">58</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">59</option>
                                    <option value="[object Object]">60</option>
                                </select></div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-full md:w-9/12">
                        <div>
                            <div class="flex flex-col p-2 border border-slate-300 m-1 shadow-lg">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="w-full">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div>
                                                <div class="w-full">
                                                    <div class="flex flex-row justify-between">
                                                        <div class="w-3/4">
                                                            <div class="p-6"><!---->
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <div class="w-full">
                                                                        <h1 class="titulo">Data
                                                                            Experimental</h1>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="row"><!---->
                                                                        <h2 class="sub-titulo">Total uno</h2>
                                                                        <h3 class="detalles"></h3>
                                                                        <p></p>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="relative inline-block text-left float-left">
                                                                        <div></div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="w-1/6">
                                                            <div class="mb-4"></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="w-full">
                                                    <table class="table">
                                                        <div>HERE COME THE DINAMIC DATA</div>
                                                    </table>
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="w-full"></div>
                                    <div class="w-full"></div>
                                    <div class="w-full"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center pt-8 mt-8">
                                <div class="flex flex-wrap w-full justify-center float">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
            <footer class="footer">
                <div class="flex justify-center h-14 pt-3">
                    <p>Footer</p>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>`;

(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);

  const selectLocator = await page.locator(
    "div.flex.flex-col.p-2.m-2 > div:nth-child(5) > select"
  );

  console.log("Number of elements:", selectLocator.count());

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: What's the expected output? "third HTML element" is not really clear to me. Your code has `pico` which is nowhere in the provided HTML. BTW, avoid long hardcoded xpaths. `allTextContents` needs to be awaited, and locators don't--await the action (`allTextContents`, `count`, etc), not the declaration (`getByRole`). `const elementsCount = await locator;` does nothing.

Comment: I am trying to get an array with all-text options in the “Third select” (dropdown).  I have followed your recommendations, but I am only getting an undefined object.

Answer (score 0):

Given this HTML...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option value="0">S1-A</option>
            <option value="1">S1-B</option>
            <option value="2">S1-C</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option value="3">S2-A</option>
            <option value="4">S2-B</option>
            <option value="5">S2-C</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option value="6">S3-A</option>
            <option value="7">S3-B</option>
            <option value="8">S3-C</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

...this (might) work for you...

```
import {test, expect} from '@playwright/test';

test('sandbox', async ({ page }, testInfo) => {

    await page.goto('file://C:/development/playwright/tests/array-third-select.html');

    var labels = (await page.getByRole('combobox').nth(2).innerText()).split('\n');    

    var values = [];
    for (const option of await page.getByRole('combobox').nth(2).getByRole('option').all())
        values.push(await option.getAttribute('value'));

    console.log(`values = ${values}`);

    console.log(`labels = ${labels}`);

});
```

...yields...

```
Running 1 test using 1 worker
[chromium] › sandbox.spec.js:3:5 › sandbox
values = 6,7,8
labels = S3-A,S3-B,S3-C
  1 passed (2.0s)
```

Luck.